# Is there an API that lets me hold flight bookings for free for 7 days with verifiable PNR?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, travel-agents

I am deeply into flight booking platforms lately and have been doing a lot of research about how the flight booking platforms function. Obviously, being a software developer, I thought of leveraging some sort of API to get the cheapest flights possible for our route.

But, being in the rabithole, I came across some sites that provide you with dummy tickets. And they function in a way that the dummy tickets are usable for visa applications and in some cases also present (return ticket) to border officer to get the stamp, allegedly assuring them that you will leave the country within 7 days or so.

Some sites are onwardticket.com, dummyticket.com etc. For a few bucks, these sites provide you with a round-trip itinerary and the PNR would be verifiable on the airline's website for as much as 7 days.

So, in background, what APIs would this site be using that makes it possible for them?

Comment: I feel this is a programming question, not a travel question. Can you explain how it fits on Travel Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Willeke I feel like it's more of a disguised "how does the reservation system work" question which imho is very much travel. The fact that this is being exploited by software is almost incidental.

Comment: Note that this has been discussed here a lot, many authorities just don’t trust those bookings (and often just don’t ask for them at the visa stage), and others take a very dim view of bookings being cancelled, which can lead up to bans (as in the case of China for some types of transit visas). While plans can change, presenting a booking that you know will be cancelled can be considered deception and lead to all sorts of trouble.

Comment: @jcaron I tried to find similar threads on the topic to look for certain APIs but couldn't find any. If you are aware about some threads where similar discussion took place already, would you mind directing me to that.

Answer (score 10):

Not an expert on the subject, but my guess is that those sites use the same APIs as travel agents do - global distribution systems (GDS). A travel agent can make a "reservation" in that system, which will create a reservation in the airline's system, which will then be verifiable on the airline's website. This reservation doesn't allow travelling - it is not a ticket, but only a "proposed itinerary" if you will - and it will expire after a while if not "ticketed", which involves paying, or at least committing to pay, the fare.

So each reservation is "free" if you have access to such a system, but I'd imagine getting such access is neither free nor easy. You need to either have your own travel agency or go through a "host" agency.

dummyticket.com even offers reservations with e-ticket numbers, which probably means they buy fully refundable tickets and then cancel them - assuming the e-ticket number isn't just made up. A travel agency would usually have to post some kind of bond with airlines, which allows them to issue tickets first and pay the airline later. So they likely would just never pay anything for the ticket, but only commit to pay if the ticket is not cancelled - but they ensure that it always is.

I don't really know how those sites get away with making lots of reservations that are never actually paid for. Perhaps they are hidden among legitimate reservations made by the same host agency.

Comment: Really nice insights @EM0 and glad to learn about Global Distribution Systems (GDS). That was my exact thought, why would airlines let them book and free hold a reservation if they know it's for sure gonna get cancelled but your point on just sneaking in the batch of legit reservations make sense to me. But on the other hand, if the itenirary is valid for 7 days, then you mean to say they cancel the ticket only after 7 days? If they cancel before then won't the ticket (PNR) be invalid on airlines site?

Comment: This is the way the system works: first a reservation is created, which fixes the itinerary and price, and then payment is processed, which in several systems is not instantaneous, so the ticket can be held in "reserved" state for several days. Usually, it's the half hour between you selecting your seat and finally entering your credit card information after unselecting all the upselling options -- during this time, your ticket existing already excludes other people from selecting the same seat, so there is never a case where you make payment and your seat is gone.

Comment: So: all tickets start out as unpaid reservations. There is no way to not hand out reservations. On the other hand, immigration officers can verify whether the ticket status is "confirmed", so a pure reservation will not serve as a proof of onward travel.

Comment: @creamCheeseCoder How long an unticketed reservation remains in the system is up to the airline, I believe. Just a 2-3 days is typical, but some airlines have a "hold this fare" option where they can keep it for 7 or even 14 days for a fee. Perhaps these "dummy ticket" sites can get a reservation held longer for free or perhaps they pay a fee like that, which might explain why the airline lets them do it - i.e. the airline is in on the scam. :) But I'm only speculating here.

Comment: Just a note on status "confirmed", too: when a *reservation* status is "confirmed" it just means that the airline has confirmed that they have a seat on that flight and they're holding it for you - as opposed to you being waitlisted for a full flight. It does not mean "everything is good to go, you can check in for the flight", which is probably how the average person would understand it, but no, that requires it to be ticketed, too.

Comment: When a refundable _ticket_ is issued that of course won't expire by itself, but can be cancelled any time before the flight - and sometimes even afterwards, if unused! So for longer-lasting dummy tickets _or_ when an e-ticket number needs to be shown I can only guess they buy refundable tickets.

Comment: @EM0 I personally doubt them buying refundable tickets coz refunds are a daunting process for almost all the airlines. These dummy ticket sites running on complete automation would find it hard to go through refund process where the first name last name wont be them. And, also think about the 15$ vs buying 3-4K$ refundable ticket. It just doesn't make sense. There has to be some way.

Comment: Oh, I don't think they go through the same refund process as you and me. I think they just never have to pay in the first place, as my answers says - and that is definitely all automated.